# How to assign a an env variable in the middle of a jenkins job

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile containing a pipeline. I have set a parameter that can be optional to pass, and also a default value is set if no parameter is set:

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'MY_VAR', defaultValue: 'foo', description: 'my var that can be optional')
}
```

In the middle of the stages I would like to override (only some times, and only if some other specific parameters are passed) this 'my_var' with some other value.

So far this works:

```
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                env.MY_VAR="foobar"
            }
        }
```

but I would like to read that variable from a file, so I would like to do something like:

```
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Of course none of following work
                env.MY_VAR=$(cat /tmp/my-file)
               
                //or
                sh "new_var=$(cat /tmp/my-file)"
                env.MY_VAR=$new_var 
            }
        }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need to use script block. Defining variables in script block will allow you to use them in entire pipeline, not only in a separate stage.

```
stage ('Build') {
  steps {
    script {
      env.MY_VAR=sh returnStdout: true, script: """ cat /tmp/my-file """
      echo "${env.MY_VAR}"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use any of the groovy libraries inside the script statement.
For example, you can use the File class to read text files:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def filePath = "/tmp/my-file"
                    env.VAR = new File(filePath).text
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo env.VAR
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks a clean answer, and probably would've worked, but in my jenkins setup I got the following error: `RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String`. I don't have access to Jenkins settings, but this looks a clean solution too.